# first click on linearlayout doesn flash background click color, it just flash for second and next click

Tags: android

I try to get the effect click background color for linear layout. I've set clickable to linear layout. and from the code also I've put the click listener the setBackgroundResource.

Here it is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/llinsertmem"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="50px">
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="PUSH it"
        />   
</LinearLayout>
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the java code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout linearInsertMem = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llinsertmem);
        linearInsertMem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
                Toast.makeText(testdoank.this, "succeded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            }
        });
}
```

When first time click the clickable linearlayout, the toast text is displayed but the background color click effect doesn't. The flash background click color is only work from the second click.

any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 4):

Is not necessary do anything in JAVA code.
You can only add this as  attribute:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
```

And it works for me (on Android 2.2 device)

Answer (score 1):

After try and error, somehow it's work.
just put the setBackgroundResource also on the onCreate.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout linearInsertMem = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llinsertmem);
        linearInsertMem.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
        linearInsertMem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
                Toast.makeText(testdoank.this, "succeded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            }
        });
}
```

Don't know the logic explanation. if you have a thought, please.

Answer (score 0):

In the onClick method you are using v as the View which is passed, but that view may not be the LinearLayout which you want to change the background.
Thus you need to create a class level variable or a final varibale and pass the handle for the LineraLayout to the onClick method.
Remove/cut from onCreate:

```
linearInsertMem.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
```

and paste it into onClick or change v. into linearInsertMem.
I think that Exlipse will then demand that linearInsertMem must be final like:

```
final LinearLayout linearInsertMem = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llinsertmem);
```

Or you can define this object above onCreate like this:

```
LinearLayout linearInsertMem;
```

then in onCreate you state:

```
linearInsertMem = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llinsertmem);
```

then onClick method will know exactly which view you want to change if you use linearInsertMem.setBackgroundResource...